# Point symmetric to lines bisecting coordinate axes

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find the symmetric points of a complex number $a$ with respect to the lines which bisect the angles between the coordinate axes.

Let $a=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$.

The symmetric point of $a$ with respect to the axis $x=y$ should be $$r(\cos(\pi/2-\theta)+i\sin(\pi/2-\theta))=r(\sin\theta+i\cos\theta)$$

The symmetric point of $a$ with respect to the axis $x=-y$ should be $$r(\cos(-\pi/2-\theta)+i\sin(-\pi/2-\theta))=r(-\sin\theta-i\cos\theta)$$

Is there a simpler representation of these points. Maybe one that can be written in terms of $a$, and not $r$ and $\theta$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can be written as $i\bar a$ and $-i\bar a$, where $\bar a$ is the complex conjugate of $a$.

Comment: That's true, Henning! Is there a way to see it geometrically (not calculating out in terms of $r$ and $\theta$)?

Comment: @Paul: Negating $\theta$ corresponds to complex conjugation; then multiplying by $\pm i$ adds $\pm \pi/2$ to $-\theta$. Both operations leave $r$ unchanged.

Comment: Geometrically, any 2D reflection with respect to a line through the origin can be decomposed as reflecting across a _fixed_ line followed by (or preceded by) a rotation. In the complex numbers, conjugation is your fixed reflection, and multiplying by some $c$ of unit length is a rotation.

Comment: All clear. Thanks Henning!